# Incorrect definition of user type

Tags: c#, dictionary, containskey

I have a class that determines the user type

```
    public class Auth
    {
        public enum UserType : ushort
        {
            Admin = 0,
            User = 1,
            None = 2,
        }

        public UserType userType = UserType.None;

        private Dictionary<string, string> users;

        public Auth()
        {
        }

        public Auth(string login, string password)
        {
            users = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            users.Add( "admin", "global");
            users.Add("user", "client");

           

            if (!users.ContainsKey(login))
            {
                if (users[password] == users[login])
                {
                    if (users[login] == "admin")
                        userType = UserType.Admin;
                    else if (users[login] == "user")
                        userType = UserType.User;
                    else
                        userType = UserType.None;
                }
            }
            else
                userType = UserType.None;
```

And I have a form where login and password are entered. When you enter the correct login and password, the program incorrectly determines the user type and displays MessageBox("wrong login or password ")

```
   public partial class FormAuth : Form
    {
        private FormMain main;
        private Auth auth;
      

        public FormAuth(FormMain main)
        {
            this.main = main;
            InitializeComponent();
            this.textBoxPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
            auth = new Auth();
        }

        private void buttonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            auth = new Auth(textBoxLogin.Text, textBoxPassword.Text);
            if (auth.userType == Auth.UserType.None)
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("wrong login or password");
                    textBoxPassword.Text = "";
                    textBoxPassword.Focus();

            }
            else
            {
                main.userType = auth.userType;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

I've tried redoing the code, but I can't seem to fix it. Tell me the mistake please

Comment: You use `if (!users.ContainsKey(login))`, isn't this correct? `if (users.ContainsKey(login))`. However, this looks strange: `if (users[password] == users[login])`.

Comment: I agree, the logic `if (users[password] == users[login])` looks off. Why can't you use a bool method that checks the dictionary for IsLoginExist()? Something like `if (myDic.ContainsKey(testKey) && myDic[testKey].Equals(testValue))` instead?

Comment: If somebody inputs "admin" and "global", `users[login] == "admin"` will resolve to `"global" == "admin"`, which will always be false.